# Flutter detect the color that the "target" (small circle in middle of screen) is over

Tags: flutter

I'm making a simple game, and I am wondering how I can detect the color under a small target in the middle of the screen.

Is there some way to do this? Please forgive me, I don't really know how adding any code could help, its literally a small dot in the middle of the screen and I am trying to figure out how to find the color under the dot.

[image]

Comment: could you add any image or video so that we can get a clear idea

Comment: added the image, hope that makes sense.  in this case, how to know the color behind the dot?

Comment: something like color picker?

Comment: what do you mean? sorry I don't understand

Comment: I am trying to find the color UNDER the circle